# Scalar-Scalar-Spin(l+1/2) correlator in CFT

Tags: conformal-field-theory

Is the $\langle \phi^{(0)} \phi^{(0)} \psi^{(l)} \rangle$ in a CFT zero ? Where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are spin-0 and spin-$(l+1/2)$ fields respectively and $l$ is an integer. If so, please, explain why ? The above fields are primaries.

Comment: A correlation function must contain an even number of fermions in order to be nonzero. One way to prove this is to note that otherwise it will not be invariant under a $2\pi$ rotation.